# FileIO and exception handling errors

Tags: java, file-io, exception, applet

Ok so I'm writing some applet as a project for java class, and I want it to take a string from a `JTextArea`, another from a `JTextField`, an option from a radio button, and when the user hits "Submit", it writes all of the information onto a txt file like so:
`Quote Message - Name Message - Radio option`
Now, I've got it to where I can print out it exactly as described above, but I can't get it to print it to a txt file. This is currently what I have:

```
  private class SubmitButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
        String quoteString = quoteText.getText();
        String nameString = nameText.getText();
        String color = null;
        if(redButton.isSelected())
           color = "red";
        else if(blueButton.isSelected())
           color = "blue";
        else if(greenButton.isSelected())
           color = "green";
        System.out.println(quoteString + "-" + nameString + "-" + color); // For testing

        try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("index.txt"), "utf-8"))) {
           writer.write(quoteString + "-" + nameString + "-" + color);
        } 
           catch (IOException ex){
              ex.printStackTrace();
           } 
     }
  }
```

But when I try to execute it, I get

> "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1"
>   java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   ("java.io.FilePermission" "index.txt" "write")"

Answer (score 4):

Applets cannot read or write files on the client's file system.You need to sign your applet or edit the policy files. Look [here](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/HowCanAnAppletReadFilesOnTheLocalFileSystem) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html).

Comment: Balls. If I want to store inputs to be called up later in random order, is there any way to accomplish this?